# Query String NodeJS not getting expected result

Tags: node.js

I am trying to test a URL query string in NodeJS

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')

http.createServer(function (req,res) {
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
var q = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
console.log(q);
var txt = q.year+q.month;
res.end(txt);
console.log(txt);
}).listen(8080);
```

when i type nodejs filename and then do this
 `curl http://localhost:8080/?year=2020&month=Jan`

I get output as `2020undefined`

Not sure why the month is not getting printed

Could someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is correct and it returns the expected output if you visit the mentioned url in the browser. The problem is not with the code but instead of `&` in terminal.

Try

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/?year=2020&month=Jan"
```

P.S. I tested on Windows.

Comment: Anytime Welcome @KKR

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this instead of parsing the whole url.

```
var txt = req.query.year + req.query.month;
console.log(txt);
```

As by this I am getting output as follow:

```
2020Jan
```

Postman url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/project/get/allUser?year=2020&month=Jan
```